# swift - how can i use #available inside a switch statement

Tags: swift, macos, switch-statement

How can I use #available in a swift switch statement? Here is some sample code but of course I would like it to use in iOS too. Or if #available is not useable here what could I use?

```
private func checkStatusAndGetAllEvents() -> String {
    var eventResult: String = "What?"
    let currentStatus = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: EKEntityType.event)switch currentStatus {
    case .authorized:
        eventResult = "authorized"
    case .notDetermined:
        eventResult = "notDetermined"
        eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event) { accessGranted, error in
            if accessGranted {
                eventResult = "notDetermined not granted"
            } else {
                eventResult = "Change Settings to Allow Access"
            }
        }
    case .restricted:
        eventResult = "restricted"
    case .denied:
        eventResult = "denied"
    ////////////////////////////
    if #available(macOS 13, *) {
            // Run code in macOS 13 or later.
        case .fullAccess:
            eventResult = "fullAccess"
        case .writeOnly:
            eventResult = "writeOnly"
    }
    @unknown default:
        eventResult = "default"
    }
    return eventResult
}
```

Any suggestions, or should I create a dozen of switch statements?